# Nexus 5 kitkat; my app is reported as high battery use; shows GPS on for lengthy time even though not doing location polling

Tags: android

my app is not doing polling updates. It displays a simple map and just calls "getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);"

on a Nexus 5 android 4.4.2 - it reports my app as using most of the current battery drain 70% my app - 80ish% total battery remaining; (and Google Play Services as minor 2% ?). and on further details it seems to indicate that GPS is on the whole time for my app.

I tried (although it didn't seem necessary) adding in onPause() and onStop() a call for getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(false); didn't change anything with the 'battery usage' reporting.

under 'Location' I found a spot to change 'mode' to 'Device only - GPS' and now it indicates my app (and Google Play Services) under this Location area as "Low Battery use."

how can i control it better?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it is neither false nor misleading.

You are the one who called `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`. Hence, it is your app that triggering any battery drain due to location lookups that Maps V2 elects to do as a result of this and any user interaction with the my-location layer. It is perfectly reasonable -- and, from the user's standpoint, far more accurate -- to indicate that your app is the battery consumer.

If you wish to control that battery drain, you are welcome to implement [the `LocationSource` interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource) and associate an instance with your `GoogleMap` via `setLocationSource()`. Then *you* are responsible for obtaining location data, and you can tailor your use of `LocationManager` or `LocationClient` to try to consume less power, albeit perhaps with a commensurate loss of accuracy.

Or, do not activate the my-location layer via `setMyLocationEnabled(true)`.

Or, give the user control over whether the my-location layer is enabled, such as via an action bar item.

Comment: ok sorry for that wording. i am just confuse as to how its using that much battery even when the app isn't in the foreground or on the map feature - why does GPS stay on? is that what is happening? Other devices like my Galaxy S3 do not report the app as high battery use.

Comment: adding a action bar item to turn 'find me' on or off might be a nice solution. thanks for the suggestion. although i hope by having setMyLocationEnabled(false) in onPause() and onStop() that the app would not be using location services while it's not in use.

Comment: @user3411527: "why does GPS stay on?" -- that's a fine question, though not one somebody here on StackOverflow is likely to be able to answer. You might wish to [file an issue about it](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Android2&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Internal+Stars&cells=tiles), ideally providing a sample app and steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user3411527: You might also consider turning the my-location layer off in `onPause()` or `onStop()`, so it is not active while you are not in the foreground. Note that there may be some lag in reactivating it, as the device tries to re-acquire a GPS fix.